# How to rotate a cube on all $3$ axes?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I have a cube that I want to turn along 3 axes, ($x$, $y$, and $z$), and I don't know how to do this.

I started by rotating a square, and I used trigonometry to rotate each vertex. I got the radius and used the formula **$r\cdot \operatorname{trig}(θ)$** where r is the radius and $\theta$ (theta) is the angle at which I want to rotate the square. "trig" is either sine or cosine, used with the y and x coordinates.

I can then copy this method to 2 faces of the cube and I am able to rotate the cube along an axis.

How would I rotate a cube along all 3 axes?
(This is using computer algorithms, $\theta$ isn't a set angle, and the cube can lie at any $xyz$ coordinate)

Comment: What does rotating something "along all three axes" mean to you? If you can do each rotation individually, then you can do them one after the other if you want to, right?

Comment: Rotating along all three axes is where I can have 3 angles, and the cube will rotate based on the three angles.

Comment: Plural of *axis* is *axes*

Comment: Sorry, thank you!

Comment: @PythonUser But how are you suggesting to interpret those three angles as a single rotation? Rotations in 3D space don't even have three degrees of freedom.

Comment: So you have a total of three rotations. Their combination depends on the order in which the three rotations are applied. Please specify.

Comment: MishaLavrov The rotations are separate, each affects the cube. JyrkiLahtonen wouldn't the rotations all add up to the cube facing the same direction no matter what the order is?

Comment: "... wouldn't the rotations all add up to the cube facing the same direction no matter what the order is?" No, this is definitely not true except in a few special cases. Try it with an actual cube where you can tell which face is which. Rotate around the $x$ axis and then the $z$ axis. Then try it in the opposite order.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: Rotations are linear transformations so you can use matrices to calculate them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: @CyclotomicField thank you!